# Node Buffer.readFloatBE() extends data to 64-bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

When converting data to/from a Buffer using 32-bit floating point numbers, it seems that nodejs extends the float to double using some criteria that makes the transformation not reversible:

```
> f=3.81357913e+32
3.81357913e+32

> b.Buffer.alloc(4)
<Buffer 00 00 00 00>

> b.writeFloatBE(f)
4

> b
<Buffer 75 96 6b 4f>
```

So it seems that the original value (3.81357913e+32) is represented as 0x75966b4f (Big endian IEEE-754, single precision)
Now, when you read the same value, you get a different value:

```
> b
<Buffer 75 96 6b 4f>

> b.readFloatBE()
3.813579129065691e+32
```

So the two values are different.  I would expect the two values to be the same. It seems the `readFloatBE()` produces a 64-bit double-precision with arbitrary values.

I understand when rounding a double to a float, you lose precision. All the following numbers when reduced to float have the same encoded value:

```
3.813579129099999e+32  -> 0x75966b4f
3.813579129065691e+32  -> 0x75966b4f
3.813579129000000e+32  -> 0x75966b4f
```

... but where is this value (3.813579129065691e+32) comes from?

(Tested with node.js v.11.12.0)

Answer (score 0):

0x75966b4f, when converted to a lot of precision, is 3.813579129065691e+32.

Normally, a FLOAT is displayed only to the available precision, which is about 7 decimal digits.  It looks like they converted to double, adding zeros to fill out to DOUBLE precision.  Such would normally be represented to about 16 significant decimal digits, such as 3.813579129065691e+32.

Some languages abuse the term "float" to mean any floating point number.  IEEE-754 has specific meanings for "float" and "double", as above.